# convert whole csv to json file- python

Tags: python, json, csv, geojson

The following code does not give me any errors when executed. However, when I drag/drop the file into url: geojson.io I get the following "invalid Json file:Syntax error unexpected token".

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import json
import geojson

csvfile = open('May_6th.csv', 'rU')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features':[("Name","Bearing (True)","Bearing (Mag)",
"Distance","Total Distance","Planned Speed", 
"Leg Time", "Total Time", "Turn", "Latitude", "Longitude")]}

reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)



for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
print 'csv file converted'
```

Comment: When I edit the script- I only end up getting additional error when the script is executed in python.

Comment: What do you mean "drag/drop the file into url: geojson.io"?  Are you saying you tried to paste this code into the input box on that web page?  That doesn't make any sense.  What you wrote is Python code, it's not geojson, so you can't paste it in where geojson is expected.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: why are you `jsonfile.write('\n')`?

Comment: BrenBarn- You can drop a *.json extension file into geojson.io. I have done so in a python class- where the script is written in python. I am aiming to to the same with my csv file of lat and longs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By most conventions, a JSON file represents a single javascript object. Your file is a series of objects, separated by newlines. What you're creating is sometimes called [JSRec](http://www.huyng.com/posts/json-streaming-record-data-format/).

More to the point, there's no sign that you're making valid geojson. You import the library but you don't use it. You should probably review the docs at https://github.com/frewsxcv/python-geojson or the [GeoJSON format specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) to make sure that the file you're creating adheres to the GeoJSON format.

I note that the GeoJSON spec says specifically:

> GeoJSON always consists of a single object. This object (referred to as the GeoJSON object below) represents a geometry, feature, or collection of features.

Comment: You can seemingly paste json into geojson.io so the geojson is probably not needed.

Comment: I will try it without the geojson. But Joe the geometry is a MultiLineString (since I want to connect all of the points into a 'trackline', my feature is Name, and the remaining columns I have are: Bearing (True), Bearing (Mag), Distance, Total Distance, Planned Speed, Leg Time, Total Time, Turn, Latitude, Longitude. Would all of these be the FeatureCollection (without Lat and Long)....????

Comment: example data:                                                                                     Name|Bearing (True)|Bearing (Mag)|Distance|Total Distance|           Planned Speed|Leg Time|Total Time|Turn|Latitude|Longitude
2 244.115796 228.012487 0.069682 0.069682                          8.5   30 30 69 47.648986 -122.314021

Comment: @darcye to be honest, I haven't constructed geojson from raw data myself; I've only used it as the output of GIS tools. Best to consult the docs. Or, maybe someone else will write a more complete answer.